# Delete Duplicate Rows If A & F Match - Google Sheets / Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If any Row in Column A & Column F ONLY are duplicated - Delete row with the oldest Date/s(if more than 1)

You can see below that Column A has A40760 Twice & Column F New Location the same A11A2.

So Script would delete the Yellow row.

[image]

As always thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your keys are rather unique, you can merge them and use a simple filter, e.g.

```
function deleteDup(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet(); 
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);

  var found = {};
  var values = data.filter(function(row){
    var key = row[0] + row[5]; // A & F
    if(key in found) 
      return false;
    found[key] = 1;
    return true;
  })

  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).setValue('');
  sheet.getRange(2,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Roma. Worked as intended.